# Did GCP change their OS-Login feature?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-account, google-iam

Trying to use OS-login from my account, which has the owner role and compute os login admin role to connect to an instance with enable-oslogin TRUE.  This used to work well (maybe a week or more ago), but lately it has been giving me this error.

This is within the same organization, same project.  So not sure where the error is coming from.

Did GCP change their OS-Login feature?  I am unable to find anything in the release notes.

gcloud compute ssh **instance**
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) User [**user**] does not have permission to access user [**user**:importSshPublicKey] (or it may not exist): Insufficient IAM permissions. The instance belongs to an external organization. You must be granted the roles/compute.osLoginExternalUser IAM role on the external organization to configure POSIX account information.

Comment: You have the solution. Did you assign the required role? Google sometimes improves security and assigning roles might be necessary. `You must be granted the roles/compute.osLoginExternalUser IAM role on the external organization`

Comment: @JohnHanley Can you possibly elaborate? Suppose there's user UA, who is not part of the organization OA. Some user UB, who is part of OA and has enough permissions should grant UA role `roles/compute.osLoginExternalUser` on OA? I.e. UB should do something along the lines of `gcloud organizations add-iam-policy-binding OA --member user:UA --role roles/compute.osLoginExternalUser`? I'm facing the [same issue](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/bd419cba635a7118cdd54a566d7d9887). Apparently my user doesn't belong to any organization, and I was given `roles/owner` on some projects.

Answer (score 0):

The GCP message is saying that you are running the gcloud tool with a credential that don’t belongs to the same organization from the project.

Try to run “gcloud auth list” to validate the authenticated user.

If the user is incorrectly select run the gcloud config command to change the logged user or gcloud auth login to log with the proper credentials.

I wish that this can help you,
Eduardo Ruela